# What's the difference between assigning a value to a dictionary manually and using the updateValue function?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I'm currently learning swift and I wonder what the difference is between assigning a value to a dictionary and using the updateValue function. Both of them either change or add a dictionary with the name that you've entered and the value you have passed to that name.

```
var states = [ "La" : "Las Vegas", "Ca" : "California", "We" : "Whatever" ]

//manually assigning/changing a value
states["La"] = "Ive changed"
println(states["La"])

//using the updateValue function
states.updateValue("Ive changed again", forKey: "La")
println(states["La"])
```

They're both giving me the same results, the question is if I'm thinking right or not, I just want to know whether I should use the first or the second option and when.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one difference, when you use `updateValue` for updating a dictionary, it'll update/insert the value and also return the previous value stored in the key. (If that key is not present return nil)

You can use that like:

```
if let unwrappedPreviousValue = dictionary.updateValue("Midhun", forKey: "La")
{
    println("Previous value: \(unwrappedPreviousValue)")
}
```

According to [Swift Standard Library Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Dictionary.html):

> **updateValue(_:forKey:)**
>
> Inserts or updates a value for a given key and returns the previous
>   value for that key if one existed, or nil if a previous value did not
>   exist.
>
> **Declaration**
>
> `mutating func updateValue(value: Value, forKey key: Key) -> Value?`
>
> **Discussion**
>
> Use this method to insert or update a value for a given key, as an
>   alternative to subscripting. This method returns a value of type
>   Value?—an optional with an underlying type of the dictionary’s Value